# Passing values from one function to another in python

Tags: python

Trying to pass value from one function to another

## function to input a number

```
def compute2():
    x=input("enter a number")
    num=int(x)
    print(num)
    return num

#function to find primes
def compute1(num):
    
   
   a = []
   for i in range(2,num+1):
     for j in range(2,i):
         
         if((i % j) == 0):
              
              break;
     else:
                 a.append(i)
   return a


#function for finding lcm
def compute(a):
     count=0
     
     
     b=[]
     
     for i in a:
           
           for j in range(1,20):
               if(i**j<20):
                   count=count+1
           b.append(count)
           count=0
     print(b)
     z=1
     for x in range(0,8):
         z= z * a[x]**b[x]
     print(z)
     return z      
                  
           
     
              
if __name__ == "__main__":
    compute2()
    compute1(num)
    compute(a)
```

I am getting the error 'num' not defined and 'a' not defined in the main function. I am trying to clear my basics. How to pass the argument and list

Comment: `num=compute2()` you have a return but you don't assign it to variable

Answer (score 1):

`num` and `a` are local values to the functions. You are not defining them anywhere.

To achieve what you are trying to do,

```
num = compute2()
a = compute1(num)
compute(a)
```

or

```
compute(compute1(compute2()))
```